# Assembly substraction

Tags: assembly, operations

Hello i started to learning basic 6502 assembly. Unfortunately i encountered first problem. I put code here and my opinion's what's doing what.

```
> LDA #$5            <-- we put value $5 in register A(accumulator) STA
> STA$01            <--  we store vaule of A in memory $01 LDA #$8          
> LDA #$8           <--  we load value $8 to A  SBC $01         
> SBC $01          <---  accumulator a number stored in $01;
```

Now, when i am using this site: http://skilldrick.github.io/easy6502/#registers

After going through all steps my accumulator is not $3. It is $2. It seems that i dont understand sth.
Could u point where i do a mistake? I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `C` in `SBC` stands for `Carry`. If the Carry flag is clear, `SBC` subtracts an extra 1.

Always do `SEC` before a lone `SBC`, or before the first in a series of `SBC`'s implementing a multi-byte subtraction, the same way you do `CLC` before an `ADC` or series of `ADC`'s.